# AngularJS Filter Large Collection in Controller w/o $watch()

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working on an application that has a rather large amount of data that needs to be displayed on the screen. Also, this data is in a tabular format which unfortunately results in a few ng-repeats on the page. As a result, in an effort to speed things up I'm pre-filtering the data in the controller as opposed to the view.

So, for example, instead of doing something like this:

```
app.controller('PersonController', function($scope, People) {
    $scope.items = People.query(); 
});

<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'name'"></div>
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
app.controller('PersonController', function($scope, People) {
    $scope.items = People.query();
    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.items, 'name')
});

<div ng-repeat="item in filteredItems"></div>
```

This works initially, except once I start trying to add/update/remove items on the $scope.items collection. This does not trigger an update to $scope.filteredItems.

I know that I could use $watch to update $scope.filteredItems like this in the controller:

```
$scope.$watch 'items', (->
    $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.items, 'name')
), true
```

However, this is not ideal since the $scope.items collection is very large and this $watch call would be very expensive.

Can anyone help me figure out a better way to do this? Any help would be really appreciated! :)

Comment: If $scope .items is modified outside of the controller then you will need to use $watch to detect changes in the array. If you are only concerned with add \ remove you could watch $scope.items.length

Comment: Do you have an example showing the performance issue?

Comment: I have used ng-repeat on data sets with over 500,000 rows, for scalability testing, and the filtering and sorting done by ng-repeat is speedy. The DOM rendering and total watch count gets out of hand so you need to have paging or virtual scrolling on the table.